# How can i import JSON into Cloud Firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am currently using Firebase Realtime database. I have imported JSONs into Realtime database but due to limitation of query i need to switch on Firebase Firestore.

I want to import JSONs into Cloud Firestore of Firebase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no automatic conversion from Firebase's Realtime Database to Cloud Firestore. While both are NoSQL databases and part of Firebase, their data models are different, and they are not compatible in any way.

You will have to figure out how you want to map your JSON data from Realtime Database, to the collection/document model of Cloud Firestore, and then write code against the APIs of the databases to port the data over.

Also see:

- [Migrate Firebase Realtime Database to Firestore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46572567/migrate-firebase-realtime-database-to-firestore)
- [Converting Firebase Database to Cloud Firestore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46639693/converting-firebase-database-to-cloud-firestore)
- [Firebase Realtime Database to Cloud Firestore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53930553/firebase-realtime-database-to-cloud-firestore)
- Blog post: [Migrating from Firebase Realtime Database To Firestore — pricing and limits](https://medium.com/@vokod/migrating-from-firebase-realtime-database-to-firestore-pricing-and-limits-e1e55bf5b96)
- Blog post: [Survival guide: how to migrate from the Firebase Realtime Database to Cloud Firestore](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/rtdb-to-firestore-fd8da8149877/)